# Change max length of title in a custom block added via a template file

Tags: nodes, blocks

A drupal 7 website has a custom block added via a template file. The block displays previews of article content type belonging to a certain rubric. It uses the following line to do so:

```
$block = module_invoke('views', 'block_view', 'given-block-name'); echo render($block['content']);
```

The articles displayed have their titles truncated at the length of 50 characters. I could not find the number 50 in the files on the hosting, so it should be somewhere in the database, and so somehow changeable via the admin panel. Yet I am having a very hard time finding where to change this number. I have changed the length of the teaser for the article content, but that apparently bears no influence on what is displayed in the given block.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this seems very specific and I don't think it's likely to help someone else.

Comment: This is a View block. Things to check: Go to Admin > Structure > Views, find the View and check if it has any formatters applied to the title. If it displays nodes in a certain view mode, go to the node type's display settings and check if in this particular view mode has any formatters applied to the title (title field).

Comment: If you are embedding a view you should be able to limit the character count within that.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the setting was hidden block display -> preview -> edit directly in preview.